# How to partition a list of tuples around an element in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, partitioning

I have a list of sorted tuples that are `(x, y)` coordinates in a plane and I want to partition the points around a middle element. The points are sorted with respect to the point's x-coordinates.

```
P = [(-4.6, 1), (-2.5, -3), (-1.3, 5), (6, -2)]
```

I want to split `P` into two roughly equally sized lists of points using their x-coordinates. I'm not sure how to implement that. Here's what I tried

```
def partition(P):

    n = len(P)
    middle  = P[n // 2][0]
```

But `middle` returns a tuple, and I'm not sure how to partition `P` around `middle`'s x-coordinate. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it. Just needed to use *slicing* to get a sublist rather than indexing which returns an element.

```
def partition(P):
    mid = len(P) // 2
    return P[:mid], P[mid:]
```